# Google one tap in android

Tags: android, google-one-tap

I'm useing Google one tap for signup and signin users in my android app.
So,I make AndroidClient in GoogleCloud and my app is work correctly.
After few days I had reinstall Android studio, when Android Studio is reinstalled :
My app's `SHA1` in `debug.keystore`  was changed and I also changed it in my project in `Google Cloud --> myProject`

Now `Google one tap` is not working properly and my result is :
Result code = 0

`RESULT_CANCELED`

```
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(),
            result ->
            {
                Log.d("onetap", result.getResultCode() +"");
                if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK)
                {
                    SignInCredential credential;
                    try {
                        credential = oneTapClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(result.getData());
                        String idToken = credential.getGoogleIdToken();
                        String username = credential.getId();
                        Uri prof = credential.getProfilePictureUri();
                        String name= credential.getDisplayName();
                        String profileUrl = Objects.requireNonNull(prof).toString();
                        sendDataToAllComponents("loggedIn",idToken, name, username, profileUrl);
                    } catch (ApiException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_CANCELED)
                {
                    
                }
            });
```

Comment: Try to add new API key with the new SHA1 in google cloud and use it in your project insted of the old one.

Comment: I do it, but not sloved.

Comment: What was the solution, I experience the same thing.